# Spark and CSV: How can you tell from an inferred schema which columns allow null?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema, scala-repl

After you have loaded a CSV file into Spark. And you are exploring from the Scala REPL. How can you tell which Columns have allowed Nulls and which ones haven't?

Comment: `df.printSchema` will show this informations: `id: long (nullable = false)`

Comment: I guess the only weird thing is the 98 something fields all show nullable = true... and I know some of them do not have missing data in the CSV